# Por que "somente" não leva acento?

Tags: acentuação

Eu vi há pouco que algum tempo atrás se escrevia **sòmente** (com acento) em Portugal (não sei de que época estavam a falar).

Eu sempre fui acostumado a escrever **somente** (sem acento), mas, de acordo com meu conhecimento, somente é uma palavra **proparoxítona** e todas as proparoxítonas deveriam ser acentuadas.

Então por que motivo "**somente**" não tem acento?

Comment: Escrevia-se "Sòmente".

Comment: Escreve-se *somente* porque todos os dicionários e praticamente toda gente, imagino, acham que a palavra é paroxítona. O acento grave não indicava a sílaba tónica; apenas a subtónica. Isto vigorou no Brasil até 1971 e em Portugal até 1973. *Só* tem acento agudo: quando se acrescenta *mente*, não podia manter o acento agudo, porque *somente* é paraoxítona; então mudava-se o acento de agudo para grave. O mesmo em *rápido* - *ràpidamente*, *má* - *màzinha*, etc.

Comment: Talvez ajude comparar *somente* com *eles **somem-te*** ou *eles **comem-te***. A palavra *somem* (de *sumir*) e o clítico *te* pronunciam-se como uma palavra só, e o acento tónico está no ***so***, portanto o conjunto *somem-te* é pronunciado como uma proparoxítona. Para os meus ouvidos pelo menos, *somem-te* difere de *somente* precisamente na localização da sílaba tónica.

Comment: @Jacinto acho que esta pergunta está a precisar de uma resposta com isso que descreves nestes comentários. ;) Uma perceção alternativa à da resposta principal.

Comment: @ANeves, vou pensar no assunto :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pode ser uma divergência regional, já que eu sou brasileiro, mas **somente** é uma palavra **paroxítona**, e, por isto, não é acentuada. Esta pronúncia é consistente com os demais advérbios construídos pela junção de um adjetivo e o sufixo "mente", todos eles paroxítonos: *dificilmente*, *paradoxalmente*, *certamente*, etc.

Edit: De acordo com o dicionário Aulete Digital, ["somente" é uma palavra paroxítona](http://www.aulete.com.br/somente). Este [link da ISCTE-IUL](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/palavras-derivadas-somente-sozinho/5565) explica em mais detalhes.

Comment: Então. Eu também sou brasileiro, mas eu falo [**sómente**] e não [**somênte**]

Comment: Com a sílaba tônica em "só"? É uma pronúncia que me é estranha, não me lembro de a ter ouvido alguma vez na vida. Procurei no Google Tradutor e a pronúncia é claramente "**so**mente". Também procurei no Youtube e os dois primeiros vídeos também usavam a pronúncia "**so**mente" (fontes [1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UuEMXmpsErQ) e [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yvq4Wyuc58I)). Você teria como me mostrar esta pronúncia, por favor?

Comment: No video do mogli, pra mim, eles falam **só**mente. O outro eu ainda não vi.

Comment: @jbueno *Somente*, já foi grafado *sòmente*, tal como *ràpidamente, estùpidamente*, etc. Todas estas palavras são paroxítonas (nunca as ouvi pronunciar doutra forma), mas a vogal que antes tinha o acento grave tem um acento tónico secundário, e era isso que o acento gráfico grave assinalava. Esses acentos foram abolidos em 1971 no Brasil e, creio, também nesse ano em Portugal.

Comment: Interessante. Para mim, a ênfase parece clara no "so**me**nte", mas com o *ó* aberto. O "só" seria uma sílaba subtônica, que tem uma ênfase maior que as demais sílabas átonas, mas o pico da pronunciação estaria na sílaba do meio. O único link que encontrei a respeito seria este daqui, de uma faculdade portuguesa, mas não consegui verificar a confiabilidade: https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/palavras-derivadas-somente-sozinho/5565

Comment: Ramon, era isso mesmo que os acentos graves antes de 1971 assinalavam: uma sílaba subtónica com ênfase superior às restantes subtónicas (o que eu chamei acento tónico secundário). Era por isso que o acento era grave: o agudo e circunflexo eram reservados para a sílaba tónica. Os dicionários que indicam pronúncia mostram a sílaba tónica no *men*: [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/somente); [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/somente).

Comment: @Jacinto Excelente pesquisa. Muito obrigado pela explicação. Vou editar a resposta para incluir os links.

Comment: Quando eu era um "putinho" e estava na escola primária no Rio de Janeiro, aprendi que a palavra "só" tinha acento agudo e que ao se acrescentar o sufixo "mente", o acento aagudo tornava-se grave.  E tinha mais alguns exemplos que não recordo.  Depois, um pouco mais crescido, quando eu já era um "puto", veio a reforma ortográfica e acabou com esse acento.

Comment: Claramente em pt-BR "somente" é uma palavra paroxítona.  **"Ninguém"**, repito, **"ninguém"** deste lado do Atlântico pronuncia de outra forma.

Comment: Acho que quiseram dizer que a pronuncia é sómênte por causa do 'o' aberto. Daí tente pronunciar somente como trópico; não é a mesma coissa. Ocorre também que em alguns estados do nordeste brasileiro adotam pronuncias de 'o' e 'e' abertas que deslocam um pouco a sílaba tônica de lugar, ou adicionam sílabas tônicas e fica sóménte.

Comment: A questão então se resume ao acento **subtônico** que não é normalmente ensinado e é fácil de confundir. Segundo a regra do português, se escrevêssemos "sómente", teríamos que encurtar um pouco as sílabas seguintes, o que não é o caso, pois o *men* continua com a duração normal. Outras línguas podem ter entendimentos diferentes, por exemplo em espanhol se escreve "rápidamente". Línguas que diferenciam a duração das vogais também podem ter um entendimento diferente do que é uma *verdadeira* sílaba tônica.